# Angularjs how to handle a 2 dimensional array from php (json)

Tags: php, arrays, json, angularjs

I'm creating a site with php, angularjs etc.
There is a view/state (ui-router) which triggers a service to query the Active Directory for information of people in a specific country.
So far this works. I receive the information from the php file.

The information received is a json-encoded 2 dimensional array from the php and looks like:

```
{"Sweden":["Larsson","Svensson"],"Poland":["surname1","surname2"],"Italy":["surname3","surname4"],"Malta":["surname5"]}
```

The controller looks like:

```
$scope.fetch = function(){
        var members = countryService.read();
        members.then(function(response){
            $scope.members = response.data;
            console.log('read succesful');
        });
    }
    $scope.fetch();
```

So all the information is available in ($scope.)members

The question now is, how do I loop through this information that it will look like:

```
Country: Sweden
Members: Larsson
         Svensson
Country: Poland
Members: surname1
         surname2
```

and so on...

ps. {{members}} in the view works. I see the json string as above..

thank you

Answer (score 1):

@charlietfl

Yes, but I can't get the associative part right in my php code...
I'm not able to set the 'country':'Sweden' And then add persons...

*Later on, when things are working well with displaying the info in the (ui-)view, I'll add more information regarding the person(s).*

Anyway, here's the php snippet:

```
$countrySupport = array();
    $temp = array();
    $count = 0;
        //looping through filtered array for per country information...
    foreach($countryResult as $country){
        
        for($y=0;$y<$entries['count'];$y++){
            if(ISSET($entries[$y]['co'][0]) && $entries[$y]['co'][0] == $country){
                array_push($temp,$entries[$y]['sn'][0]);
               
            }
            
        }
        $countrySupport[$country]=$temp; 
        unset($temp);
        $temp = array();
        $count++;
        */
        
    }
```

where countryResult is the Array with countries found in an AD group.
then I loop through all entries and see if that persons country matches the countryResult array....if so, the person is added to that 'country' in the countrySupport array.

Comment: Does `$entries` contain the members?

Comment: $entries basically contains all attributes from the person (results)

Comment: That really doesn't tell me much

Comment: $entries is the result of the AD query. so e.g. $entries[0]['co'][0] is the first "country" in the query result.  $entries[1]['co'][0] the second etc. So what I do, I have an array with countries...with the foreach I go through this array. If the country matches the $entries[0]['co'][0], I need to add e.g. the lastname to that country. The result should be that I will have an array with the people under a certain country. And this I need for displaying on the main page....

Answer (score -1):

You will have a much simpler time if you change the php response data structure to use non associative outer arrays that contain objects with consistent key names along the lines of :

```
[
  {
    "country": "Sweden",
    "members": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Larsson"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

Example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('main', ($scope, $q) => {
    fakeFetch().then(response => {
      $scope.members = response.data;
    });

    function fakeFetch() {
      var def = $q.defer();
      def.resolve({data})
      return def.promise
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
  <div ng-repeat="item in members track by $index">
    <div>Country: {{item.country}}</div>   
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="mem in item.members track by $index">
         {{mem.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  const data = [{
      "country": "Sweden",
      "members": [{
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Larsson"
        },
        {
          "id": 18,
          "name": "Svensson"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "country": "Malta",
      "members": [{
          "id": 7,
          "name": "Foo"
        },
        {
          "id": 33,
          "name": "Bar"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: I've used an "answer" to show the php code to build the array. I can't get the associative part correct...due to the two dimensional array I have to fill in the loops....